# Looking to select a row from the database using DATETIME

Tags: mysql

I have the following query

```
SELECT * FROM ".TBL_FOOT_GAMES." ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1
```

I need to add a `WHERE` clause on the field `date_confirmed`.

`date_confirmed` is a `DATETIME` type.

I need to select only rows that are within 7 days of the current moment.

MORE CODE

```
SELECT g.home_user, g.away_user, g.home_score, g.away_score, g.id AS gameid, g.date_confirmed, 
       hu.username AS home_username, au.username AS away_username, ht.team AS home_team, at.team AS away_team
       FROM tbl_foot_games g INNER JOIN tbl_users hu ON hu.id = g.home_user INNER JOIN tbl_users au ON au.id = g.away_user 
       INNER JOIN tbl_foot_teams ht ON ht.id = g.home_team INNER JOIN tbl_foot_teams at ON at.id = g.away_team
       WHERE (g.type = '1' OR g.type = '2' OR g.type = '3' OR g.type = '4') AND g.status = '3' AND g.date_confirmed BETWEEN NOW() AND DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 50 WEEK)
       ORDER BY g.id DESC LIMIT 1
```

The statement works fine until I add the WHERE clause for the 50 week interval.

Comment: What have you tried? The documentation lists all sorts of date-related operators and functions.

Comment: Could you format that new query please? It's completely illegible.

Answer (score 1):

Presuming only seven days *in the future* (it looks like you're going to list upcoming football games):

```
SELECT *
  FROM `tbl`
 WHERE `date_confirmed` BETWEEN NOW() AND DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 WEEK)
 ORDER BY `id` DESC
 LIMIT 1
```

Please read [the documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html) first next time; the answers are all there.

Comment: It's 7 days in the past. Does that mean DATE_SUB?

Comment: When i add this WHERE clause, I go from getting results to zero results being returned...I'll add some sample code to the question.

Comment: @Luke: That's what `WHERE` does; it adds a conditional constraint. If you have no results, then there are no rows within that date range; _that's the whole point_.

Comment: Of course, but there are results within 50 weeks. So without it, it shows all result. Once added (all results are within 30 weeks max), it just gives me no rows.

Comment: @Luke: Then there are no rows within 30 weeks. MySQL doesn't lie, and you haven't given me anything further to go on...

Answer (score 0):

```
... WHERE date_confirmed BETWEEN NOW() AND DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 7 DAY) ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the `NOW()` and `DATE_SUB()` functions.

These should let you create a date 7 days ago, then in your where clause you can check that the datetime column is greater than this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `date_sub` function of MySQL to see if the diff is 7 days or less.

```
SELECT * FROM ".TBL_FOOT_GAMES." 
WHERE DATE_ADD(DATE_CONFIRMED, INTERVAL '7 00:00:00' DAYS_SECOND) >= TIMESTAMP(CURDATE())
ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1
```

If you are interested in seeing only 7 days of difference from current date (ignoring the time value), then you can use `DATEDIFF` function like this:

```
SELECT * FROM ".TBL_FOOT_GAMES." 
WHERE DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), DATE_CONFIRMED) <= 7
ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1
```